# How to use singleton object into a objective-C Block

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, singleton, block

```
 Using a singleton object in a block will create a strong reference cycle in the code ?
```

As I have more then 5 singleton object in application.

Comment: singleton object is always strong reference

Comment: Code? What have you tried?  What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: As you said "singleton object is always strong reference", So If I pass the singleton object to a block(as block always copy the object) will it increase the memory reference count ?

Comment: any object with a strong reference cycle inside block will increase reference count.

Comment: @Rishi, How I Can avoid this ?

Comment: you can use __weak not sure

Comment: @iShameem - you have to use weak reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use weak reference of singleton inside blocks.

```
YourSingleton *singletonInstance = ---- //get your singleton instance here

typeof(YourSingleton) __weak weakSingletonInstance = singletonInstance;

// your block
^
{
   // Now use weakSingletonInstance inside the block.           
}];
```